# for linked server could not INSERT INTO table because of column "Id". The user did not have permission to write to the column

Tags: sql, sql-server, remote-server

I am trying to copy over the missing rows from one MS sql server to the other, by using following query.
I know connection works because up to insert the joined select works fine.

```
insert into [192.168.0.200].webanalyzer.dbo.sale
select * from WebAnalyzer.dbo.Sale where url COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT not in
(
    select url COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT From [192.168.0.200].webanalyzer.dbo.sale
)
```

however I am getting following error

> Msg 7344, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL"
> for linked server "192.168.0.200" could not INSERT INTO table
> "[192.168.0.200].[webanalyzer].[dbo].[sale]" because of column "Id".
> The user did not have permission to write to the column.

**How do I give permission to remote server?**

Comment: maybe that column has auto generated values, so that's why you cannot insert explicitly...can you show us the table definition?

Comment: @AndreiXwe Hi Andrei, it does. does it mean i have to select everything by column in select and insert parts?

Comment: yes, you should just use a custom select, without selecting the ID column, i will post an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `Id` column has auto generated values, you cannot use explicit inserts. So change your query to:

```
insert into [192.168.0.200].webanalyzer.dbo.sale ([columns])
select [columns] from WebAnalyzer.dbo.Sale where url COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT not in
(
    select url COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT From [192.168.0.200].webanalyzer.dbo.sale
)
```

where `[columns]` are the columns you need to insert into

Answer (score 1):

indeed as suggested in comment by @AndreiXwe permission had nothing to do with it.
It was autoincremented Id, changing sql statement to list columnts explicitly made it work.

```
insert into [192.168.0.200].webanalyzer.dbo.sale ([Url]
      ,[Title]
      ,[Subtitle]
      ,[Address]
      ,[Price]
      ,[LivingArea]
      ,[RoomCount]
      ,[PostCode]
      ,[TotalArea]
      ,[DateAdded]
      ,[DateRemoved]
      ,[DateLastProcessed]
      ,[ServiceCosts]
      ,[HeatingType]
      ,[IsBendrabutis]) 

select [Url]
      ,[Title]
      ,[Subtitle]
      ,[Address]
      ,[Price]
      ,[LivingArea]
      ,[RoomCount]
      ,[PostCode]
      ,[TotalArea]
      ,[DateAdded]
      ,[DateRemoved]
      ,[DateLastProcessed]
      ,[ServiceCosts]
      ,[HeatingType]
      ,[IsBendrabutis] from WebAnalyzer.dbo.Sale where url COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT not in
( 
select url COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT From [192.168.0.200].webanalyzer.dbo.sale
)
```